# How to specify a browser to open a custom file format?

Tags: browser, file-format

I am working on a custom file format. I want to indicate to mobile phones to open the file in a browser. Is there a special header i can append to my files that would indicate that the file should be opened in a browser?

Or is there a way to always open a png/jpeg/pdf file in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use the accept attribute for the input tag `input` with `accept` attribute

so like

`<input type="file" name="my-image" id="image" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />`

You dont have to go far in terms of research online hope this answers your question

Comment: I am asking for a way to create a new file format that operating systems would know to open in browsers. This is an input tag that accepts jpeg and png format. How does this relate to what I am asking?

Comment: you asked if there was a way to always open a png/jpeg/pdf file in browser, your question want crystal clear to me. Quick question, why dont you simply change the file association? wouldn't that resolve your problem?